# Momentum-derivative of energy when mass is not constant

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, transport-phenomena

We know by multivariable calculus, that a scalar multivariable function such the energy function $E=E(\vec{P},\vec{L},X_{0},X_{1},...,X_{n})$, using the chain rule, can be expanded as follows:
$\frac{dE}{dt}=\frac{\partial E}{\partial \vec{P}}\frac{d\vec{P}}{dt}+\frac{\partial E}{\partial \vec{L}}\frac{d\vec{L}}{dt}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial E}{\partial X_{i}}\frac{dX_{i}}{dt}$

If the energy function is define as follows:

$E=\frac{1}{2}\vec{v}\cdot\vec{P}+\frac{1}{2}\vec{w}\cdot\vec{L}+U$

where $U=U(X_{0},X_{1},...,X_{n})$ is the internal energy, then we can transform de Energy equation to

$E=\frac{\vec{P}\cdot\vec{P}}{2M}+\frac{\vec{L}\cdot\vec{L}}{2I}+U$

If we take the derivative of $E$ when mass is CONSTANT, we get:

$\frac{dE}{dt}=\frac{1}{2M}(\frac{d\vec{P}}{dt}\cdot\vec{P}+\vec{P}\cdot\frac{d\vec{P}}{dt})+\frac{1}{2I}(\frac{d\vec{L}}{dt}\cdot\vec{L}+\vec{L}\cdot\frac{d\vec{L}}{dt})+\dot{U}$

$\frac{dE}{dt}=\frac{\vec{P}\cdot\dot{\vec{P}}}{M}+\frac{\vec{L}\cdot\dot{\vec{L}}}{I}+\dot{U}$

$\frac{dE}{dt}=\vec{v}\cdot\dot{\vec{P}}+\vec{w}\cdot\dot{\vec{L}}+\dot{U}$

Using the definition $\frac{dE}{dt}=\frac{\partial E}{\partial \vec{P}}\frac{d\vec{P}}{dt}+\frac{\partial E}{\partial \vec{L}}\frac{d\vec{L}}{dt}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial E}{\partial X_{i}}\frac{dX_{i}}{dt}$

When mass is CONSTANT, we can say that $\frac{\partial E}{\partial \vec{P}}=\vec{v}$ and $\frac{\partial E}{\partial \vec{L}}=\vec{w}$

If we take the derivative of $E$ when mass is NOT CONSTANT, we get:

$\frac{dE}{dt}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\vec{P}}{M})\cdot\vec{P}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\vec{P}}{M}\cdot\frac{d\vec{P}}{dt}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\vec{L}}{I})\cdot\vec{L}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\vec{L}}{I}\cdot\frac{d\vec{L}}{dt}$

$\frac{dE}{dt}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\dot{\vec{P}}M-\dot{M}\vec{P}}{M^2}\cdot\vec{P}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\vec{P}}{M}\cdot\dot{\vec{P}}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\dot{\vec{L}}I-\dot{I}\vec{L}}{I^2}\cdot\vec{L}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\vec{L}}{I}\cdot\dot{\vec{L}}+\dot{U}$

$\frac{dE}{dt}=\frac{\dot{\vec{P}\cdot\vec{P}}}{M}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\dot{M}}{M^2}(\vec{P}\cdot\vec{P})+\frac{\dot{\vec{L}\cdot\vec{L}}}{I}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\dot{I}}{I^2}(\vec{L}\cdot\vec{L})+\dot{U}$

$\frac{dE}{dt}=\vec{v}\cdot\dot{\vec{P}}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\dot{M}}{M^2}(\vec{P}\cdot\vec{P})+\vec{w}\cdot\dot{\vec{L}}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\dot{I}}{I^2}(\vec{L}\cdot\vec{L})+\dot{U}$

Now the question is:

When mass is NOT CONSTANT, how to adapt the definition $\frac{dE}{dt}=\frac{\partial E}{\partial \vec{P}}\frac{d\vec{P}}{dt}+\frac{\partial E}{\partial \vec{L}}\frac{d\vec{L}}{dt}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial E}{\partial X_{i}}\frac{dX_{i}}{dt}$ in such a way that $\frac{\partial E}{\partial \vec{P}}$ can be expressed in terms of velocites like the case when mass is constant?

What is then $\frac{\partial E}{\partial \vec{P}}$ equal to when mass is not constant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In classical mechanics mass is constant and we clearly have
$$
E=\frac{1}{2}mv^2,\quad \frac{\partial E}{\partial v}=mv,\quad \frac{\partial E}{\partial p}=v.
$$
When mass is not constant (for some reason) then we still have
$$
\frac{\partial E}{\partial p}=v.
$$
This is a reformulation of work equals force times distance where force $F$ is understood as time derivative of momentum $p\,$:
$$
E=\int_0^xF\,dx=\int_0^x\dot p\,dx=\int_0^pv\,dp.
$$
This even holds in relativistic mechanics where we know that mass does depend on $v$ and the total energy and momentum obey
$$
E=m\,c^2=\sqrt{m_0^2\,c^4+p^2\,c^2}
$$
($m_0$ is rest mass). Clearly,
$$
\frac{\partial E}{\partial p}=\frac{p\,c^2}{E}=\frac{m\,v\,c^2}{m\,c^2}=v.
$$
(Here $m$ is the relatvisic mass that depends on $v$.) Subtracting the constant rest energy from the total energy gives the kinetic energy. Thus,
$$
\frac{\partial E_{kin}}{\partial p}=v.
$$